# call a function if user clicks on the middle-right part of an image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a gallery, I'd like to go to the next image when user clicks on the image. But I need to get clicks on the middle to right part of the image to go to next image, not on the entire image.

I was trying something like this... but no success.

```
$(".imageClass").click(function(event) {
  var x = event.offsetX
  if(x > ?????????????????) {
      next = active.next();
  }
});
```

How can I know if user clicks in the right side of an image to call next one?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(".imageClass").click(function(event) {
    var x = event.offsetX;
    var width=$(this).width();
    if(x > width/2) {
        next = active.next();
    }
});
```